# creating an empty json object from dart object in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a class

```
class User{
String name;
Address address;
}
```

and

```
class Address{
String houseId;
String location;
}
```

how can I make an empty address json object

```
"user":{"name":"jack","address":{}}
```

not

```
"user":{"name":"jack","address":{"houseId":null,"location",null}}
```

I am using **json_annotation: ^3.0.1 --
   build_runner: ^1.8.0 --
  json_serializable: ^3.2.5**

in flutter

Answer (score 0):

You can add a checker on your json encoder to check if address contains values.

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> _$UserToJson(User instance) => <String, dynamic>{
  'name': instance.name,
  'address': instance.address != null ? instance.address : {},
};
```

This should encode an empty map on the json if Address inside User is null.